# How to check View null condition in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin.android application. I have a statement as below

```
 View photoresponse =_questionTypesModel.QuestionTypesContent.FindViewWithTag( Convert.ToString(questionType["id"]));
```

here I need to check the null condition for `photoresponse`, When I am trying to check as `if(photoresponse ==null)` always returns true.

```
 QuestionTypesContent
```

This is a `Linearlayout

Comment: You are checking correctly. Probably your `view` is always `null`.

Comment: My guess would be that the view tagged with the string is not in the view hierarchy: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)  We would need to see more code to figure out why that is.

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions. I  found finally it is the tags issue and I solved them